# API Error response message in VS code extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

What's the standard way for showing error message on failure response from API call, to the user in VS code extension? i.e. it comes from the Server side or it is managed in VS code extension code.

Answer (score 1):

You can show a "Toast" style notification in the bottom right of the VS Code window, you've probably seen them whilst using the editor.

Make your call, and when your logic dictates the calls fails you can call the `showErrorMessage` function.

```
vscode.window.showErrorMessage('Error Making API Call');
```

You can find more info on the method in the [Extension Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.showErrorMessage)

Comment: Thanks for answering!! I Just wanted should I show the error message coming from API directly or I should write my custom message for the user? What's the standard way used by VS code extensions?

Comment: Ah understood, not aware of any particular convention here but could be wrong! As a rule I would always display a custom message to the user and not a raw error response. I would only show the raw response in the logs or through a "More Details" button